# Custom action in RESTful service

Tags: web-services, rest, uri

I've been reading articles about RESTful services for a while, and I understand the importance of using VERBS against RESOURCES.

But there's one thing I fail to understand. What happens if we need to invoke a certain action that is not part of CRUD?

For example, consider I want to make a cat jump. Which format should we use?

Is the following RESTful?

```
http://host/cats/123/jump
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If `cats/123` represents a resource then think about it this way: that resource can have *many* states (eating, walking, sleeping, **jumping**, pissing, ...). When you are designing an API using the REST architectural style, you want to permit a client application to make allowable requests to the resource that will change its state.

In the context of `cats/123`, you could do this through a series of POST requests that will cause the state of the resource to change. Taking advantage of the hypermedia capability in REST you could create a process like the requests and responses shown below. Notice that the allowable links change as a response to the POST. Also, the client application would be coding to the properties contained in the Links array and not the actual URI's contained in the Href properties.

Request:

```
GET cats/123
```

Response:

```
{
    "Color" : "black",
    "Age"   : "2",
    "Links":[
    {
        "Food":"kibbles",
        "Method":"POST",
        "Href":"http://cats/123",
        "Title":"Feed the cat"
    },
    {
        "Scare":"yell real loud",
        "Method":"POST",
        "Href":"http://cats/123",
        "Title":"Scare the cat"
    }]
}
```

Request:

```
POST cats/123

{
    "Food":"kibbles"
}
```

Response:

```
{
    "Color" : "black",
    "Age"   : "2",
    "Tummy" : "full"
    "Links":[
    {
        "Sleep":"lap",
        "Method":"POST",
        "Href":"http://cats/123",
        "Title":"Pet the cat"
    },
    {
        "Scare":"yell real loud",
        "Method":"POST",
        "Href":"http://cats/123",
        "Title":"Scare the cat"
    }]
}
```

Comment: +1. Thanks. But I thought we should use PUT instead of POST for updating a resource? I read that POST should be used for creation ?

Comment: Unfortunately, discussions ("arguments") about the REST architectural style revolve around understanding the HTTP specifications and the definitions it contains. In brief, the [HTTP spec](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) says the PUT method is a way of sending the *entire* resource representation (an entity as updated by the client) to the server so it can replace the current representation of the resource assuming the client had the latest version. In the question, your "action" is requesting a state transition instead of a wholesale replacement of the resource with an updated version.

Comment: {Ran out of space:)} Also, POST is an accepted way of causing a resource representation to transition from one state to another.

Comment: I think this is a great answer. I would only add that there is theory and then there is folks have to actually interop with your RestAPI. Not all libraries/systems support all HTTP Verbs.  So in the wild, I find it best to stick with GET, POST, DELETE (if your really need it) and PUT (if you really really need it).

Comment: The sample API in this answer doesn't restrict which HTTP methods are used. You can limit the API you design to support just those methods. The key point to my answer is that an API that implements Fielding's REST should provide the API client the means to interact with the server without coupling actions to hardcoded URLs. In the sample API, the client code would work with the objects in the **Links** array. Since 2012, JSON specs like [HAL](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html) have been defined that are more useful than the sample I created.

Comment: I agree with you, @SiN. The resource, /cats/123, is already known to client. So Sixto Saez should have used PUT instead of POST. That is because this is an update of the resource, rather than the creation of a new resource. In fact, there is a new method that is even better suited for such a partial update: PATCH (Adnanmuttaleb's comment)

Comment: From 9 years down the road, I see that almost all the commenters missed my use of hypermedia links. They instead quibble about the proper HTTP methods to use for certain actions. Not only that, if this were a real API then a developer could simply change the referenced hypermedia link Method value from POST to PUT or PATCH **WITHOUT THE CLIENT NEEDING TO CHANGE ANY CODE**!! This is one of the things makes an HTTP API based on Fielding's definition of ReST so powerful.

Answer (score 17):

for pure Restful Design i'd recommend something like:

```
POST /cats/123/actions
```

with the body of (the type of action is defined in request :

```
{
    "actionType": "jump",
    "customActionParameter": "some value"
}
```

but this will be a overkill.
so i found it easier to follow [Google Api Design Guide for Custom Methods](https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/custom_methods):

```
POST /cats/123:jump
```

this is the method google uses in it's cloud infrastructure Api

Comment: Your first suggestion is the better answer. URIs identify resources, not methods. Correctness may seem like overkill now, but it will provide you with a flexible, scalable design, enabling you to easily extend your API in future. Returning to the original question, an even better solution is to "nounify" the method, and to then treat the resulting noun as a subresource. Thus `/cats/123/jumps`. Think of the jumps of the cat whose ID is 123.

Comment: I like the google api design guide that is referenced.

Answer (score 2):

Don't conflate the HTTP Verbs with your domain's state machine transitions or actions.

Stripe's [invoice workflow](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/invoices/workflow#workflow-transitions) provides a great example of how to represent state transitions or domain actions in a restful manner.

A action on your domain model could well be represented by a modification (PUT or PATCH) to a state or status field that would trigger workflows within your own code's state machine. For instance, in your example the jump action could also result in the same state as 3x steps, so it could be a modification to a height or altitude field. Your code would then likely implement some type of workflow management or state machine, and then you could emit your own events and validation rules based on the requested state changes, rather than based on the 'actions' performed to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the game, but because REST is about state of your resources, this would also be acceptable, if a bit verbose. This replaces a verb (which often get conflated with HTTP verbs as @developerjack noted) with an adjective or noun.

- POST /cats/123/states/jumping, or
- POST /jumpingcats/123

This syntax might make more sense for a limited set of natural states. For example with a scheduler I've done this before:

- POST /scheduler/states/stopped (stop the scheduler)
- POST /scheduler/states/started (start the scheduler)
- POST /scheduler/jobs/123/paused (pause a job)
- POST /scheduler/jobs/123/resumed (resume a job)